# Dúvida com essa query

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

Meu professor fez a seguinte query, para mostrar a quantidade total de estoque de cada produto, porém eu não entendi muito bem como ela faz para gerar a quantidade de estoque total de cada produto, segue a query:

```
SELECT SUM
  (ret.quantidade) AS quantidade,
  ret.nome_produto,
  ret.id_produto,
  ret.preco
FROM
  (
  SELECT SUM
    (p.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE,
    p.tipo_registro,
    p.id_produto,
    c.nome AS nome_produto,
    c.preco
  FROM
    estoque p
  JOIN
    administrador u ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin
  JOIN
    cadastro_produtos c ON c.id_produto = p.id_produto
  WHERE
    p.tipo_registro = 'entrada'
  GROUP BY
    p.tipo_registro,
    p.id_produto,
    c.nome,
    c.preco
  UNION
SELECT
  - SUM(p.quantidade) AS QUANTIDADE,
  p.tipo_registro,
  p.id_produto,
  c.nome AS nome_produto,
  c.preco
FROM
  estoque p
JOIN
  administrador u ON u.id_admin = p.id_admin
JOIN
  cadastro_produtos c ON c.id_produto = p.id_produto
WHERE
  p.tipo_registro = 'saida'
GROUP BY
  p.tipo_registro,
  p.id_produto,
  c.nome,
  c.preco
) ret
GROUP BY
  ret.nome_produto,
  ret.id_produto,
  ret.preco
ORDER BY
  ret.id_produto
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vamos la. 
o select se divide em 3 partes, vamos pelos dois selects internos.

1. AZUL - Busca a quantidade (SUM) de todas os registros de entrada;
2. LARANJA - Union com o select que retornas a quandidade de todos os registros de saída (valor negativo).
3. AMARARELO - Um select por fora que soma a quantidade de entrada + a quantidade de saída (negativo);

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado amigo, por responder minha dúvida.